# OpenLayers map is not instance of ol.Map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to implement a geolocation system using rails, javascript and openlayers.
The markers has 2 different layers to identify the ones who are added and the ones who's not. Here is the call:

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
        const coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
            let innerHtml = '<strong>' + feature.get('name') + '</strong>';
            console.log(map instanceof  ol.Map)
            if (layer.get('name') === "route_trash_cans_layer") {
                if (feature) {
                    innerHtml += '<p><button class="btn" onclick="unassignTrashCan(' +
                      feature.get('id') + ',' +
                      routeId + ',' +
                      "'" + layer.get('name') + "'," +
                      map +
                      ')">Quitar de la ruta</button></p>';
                    ;
                    document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = innerHtml;
                    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                }
            } else if (layer.get('name') === "trash_cans_not_in_route_layer") {
                if (feature) {
                    innerHtml += '<p><button class="btn" onclick="assignTrashCan(' +
                      feature.get('id') + ',' +
                      routeId + ',' +
                      "'" + layer.get('name') + "'," +
                      map +
                      ')">Asignar a la ruta</button></p>';
                    document.getElementById('popup-content').innerHTML = innerHtml;
                    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

In this context console.log(map instanceof  ol.Map) is true but when creating the button its added an Object:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="assignTrashCan(2,1,'trash_cans_not_in_route_layer',[object Object])">Asignar a la ruta</button>
```

If I try sending JSON.stringify(map) its gives an error like "Uncaught TypeError: cyclic object value"
Here is the called functions:

```
function changeFeatureStyle(layerName, featureId, isAssigned, map) {

    console.log(map instanceof ol.Map );
    console.log(map);
    const layer = map.getLayers().getArray().find(layer => layer.get('name') === layerName);

    if (layer) {
        const source = layer.getSource();
        const feature = source.getFeatureById(featureId);

        if (feature) {
            const imageSrc = isAssigned ? '<%= image_path("geolocation/trash_cans_BA.svg") %>' : '<%= image_path("geolocation/trash_cans_disabled.svg") %>';

            const markerStyle = new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                    src: imageSrc,
                    scale: 0.03,
                }),
            });

            feature.setStyle(markerStyle);
        }
    }
}

function assignTrashCan(featureId, routeId, layerId, mapTarget) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/routes/' + routeId + '/assign_trash_can',
        method: 'PATCH',
        data: { trash_can_id: featureId },
        success: function (response) {
            changeFeatureStyle(layerId, featureId, true, mapTarget);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}

function unassignTrashCan(featureId, routeId, layerId, mapTarget) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/routes/' + routeId + '/unassign_trash_can',
        method: 'PATCH',
        data: { trash_can_id: featureId },
        success: function (response) {
            changeFeatureStyle(layerId, featureId, false, mapTarget);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}
Anyone knows how to make it works?
```